# Creating a Dynamic Custom Cell in IOS7

Tags: uitableview, custom-component, ios7.1

I'm trying to create a custom class that extends UITableViewCell. I'm adding a boolean value (isValid) that can be set to toggle visual indicators for the validation state. When the setter for isValid gets called, it sets the property and makes a call to another method that updates the borderColor of the cell and the text color of the detailTextLabel. All the changes are being made correctly, but the cell never actually updates in my app. I have tried everything I can think of to get the cell to refresh with no success. I'm sure there is something obvious I'm missing here, someone please help!

P.S. If it helps, the Table I'm using this cell in has static row content so I don't think it a reuse issue.

**UPDATE**:
As requested here is some source code:

The Header

```
//  NewPlayerCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface NewPlayerCell : UITableViewCell

@property(strong,nonatomic) UIColor *cellColor;
@property(weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameTextField;

@end
```

Implementation

```
//
//  NewPlayerCell.m
//

#import "NewPlayerCell.h"

@implementation NewPlayerCell

- (void) setCellColor: (UIColor*)color
{
    _cellColor = color;
    [self update];

}

-(void)update
{
    if(self.cellColor!=nil)
    {
        self.contentView.layer.borderColor = self.cellColor.CGColor;
    }
    if(self.detailTextLabel!=nil)
    {
        self.nameTextField.textColor = self.cellColor;
    }
    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
@end
```

The TableView Controller

```
//Just a quick and dirty testing method that updates the color of
//any visible NewPlayCell objects in response to a button touch.
-(IBAction)colorChange:(id)sender
{
    [[self.tableView visibleCells] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if( [obj isKindOfClass:[NewPlayerCell class]])
        {
            if( [game isEqualToString:@"Chess" ])
            {
                ((NewPlayerCell *) obj).cellColor = [UIColor redColor];
            }
            else
            {
                ((NewPlayerCell *) obj).cellColor = [UIColor blueColor];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: It is hard to help you if you don't show the relevant code.

Comment: Edited the post to include some examples. Let me know if you need more.